# Adjective meaning reading "strictly for educational purposes"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I want to say:

> "I began reading this book with a ________ attitude."

Fill in the blank with a word that means strictly for educational purposes and not expecting to be empathetic. I feel it is just a matter of reading from point a to point b.

Comment: with an ***academic*** attitude?

Comment: dispassionate, pragmatic?

Comment: "grimly utilitarian"?

Answer (score 1):

> I began reading this book with a going through the motions attitude.

This means that you weren't engaged or motivated at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something positive (which does not appear to be the case), how about *educable*?

You example:

> "I began reading this book with an *educable* attitude."

From Dictionary.com:

> *educable*: capable of being educated
>
> *educate*: the act or process of imparting or acquiring general knowledge, developing the powers of reasoning and judgment, and
> generally of preparing oneself or others intellectually for mature
> life.

If you're looking for something negative (which may or may not be the case), how about *cynical*?

You example:

> "I began reading this book with an *cynical* attitude."

From Dictionary.com:

> *cynical*: bitterly or sneeringly distrustful, contemptuous, or pessimistic

If you're looking for something that is neither positive nor negative (which may be the case), how about *blase* or *indifferent*?

You example:

> "I began reading this book with a *blase* attitude."
>
> "I began reading this book with an *indifferent* attitude."

From Dictionary.com:

> *blase*: indifferent to or bored with life; unimpressed, as or as if from an excess of worldly pleasures
>
> *indifferent*: without interest or concern; not caring; apathetic

Of these options, perhaps *blase* or *indifferent* come closest to the word you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the phrase you are looking for is *check the box*.

Your example:

> I began reading this book with a *check-the-box* attitude."

From the Urban Dictionary:

> A phrase which means to complete a task to the barest minimum
>   standard, and subsequently cease working. At this point one may check
>   off the box on a task list or matrix. *I'm totally just going to check
>   the box on this English homework.*

"Check the box* definitely conveys the attitude you've described: you are "not expecting to be empathetic"; you "felt like it was just another point a to point b situation". You just needed to *check the box*. It's a very commonly used phrase in the U.S.,  when it comes to training or safety, for example.

Comment: We Brits know all about reality checks but this 'check the box' thingy is more than likely to discombobulate half the UK's population, with the other half just as likely to salivate at the prospect of checking out the contents of one's tiffin box for tasty tidbits and the like.

Comment: @PeterPoint Salutations! Do you know what you have once you have checked the box? A strange sense of gratification ... and a desire to check another box.

Comment: A strange sense of gratification, eh? Oh, that sounds quite nice. Can I sign on for this online?

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> "I began reading this book with an ***objective*** attitude."

M-W:

> **[objective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **3** a :  expressing or dealing with facts or conditions as perceived without distortion by personal feelings, prejudices, or
>   interpretations: objective art; an objective history of the war; an
>   objective judgment
>
> We need someone outside the company to give us an objective analysis.
>
> an objective assessment based solely upon the results of the
>   experiment

Also, ***open-minded*** may work.

> "I began reading this book with an ***open-minded*** attitude."

M-W:

> **[open–minded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%E2%80%93minded)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : willing to consider different ideas or opinions

Answer (score 0):

[Dutiful](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dutiful) doesn't specify that your are reading for a course, but it does seem to catch the spirit of your question:

> 1 Conscientiously or obediently fulfilling one's duty. ‘a dutiful
>   daughter’
>
> 1.1 Motivated by duty rather than desire or enthusiasm. ‘dutiful applause’ ‘a dutiful visit’

Thus:

> I began reading this book with a dutiful attitude.

You could also use the adverbial form to shorten the sentence:

> I began reading this book dutifully.